# Add new time format to the linux desktop

Tags: linux, datetime, desktop

While I understand that there is a lot of controversy around time and time standards, I would like to add something like either the internet time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) or 28-hour day (https://limedaring.com/articles/hacking-your-week-the-28-hour-day/) ideas to the Linux desktop, particularly the Debian branch of the family, however I have no idea where would be the most effective place to implement this change.

Ideally, I would like to enable Linux to support one of the above time systems, and through the use of the correct time specification format to switch my desktop clock to use one of the above specifications.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the" Linux desktop.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is about programming. It is about taking on a programming project to get these time display formats into my distribution unless if someone knows that this has already been implemented, in which case I would like to know how to enable this.

Answer (score -1):

28 hours doesn't exist yet in linux .In debian it is found in the settings menu (date and time).It has also an internet adress to configure your operating system clock with time servers or you can manually set your time.All time zones are included in in linux distributions.Be careful when you set your time zone if not correct internet programs won't work.cheers